# How to accept any type of data from sockets in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, socket.io

I'm fairly new to swift programming. I am playing with sockets and am trying to understand this snippet:

```swift
socket.on("Hello") { [weak self] (data, ack) in
    if let data = data[0] as? [String: String],
        let rawMessage = data["msg"]
    {
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self?.messages.append(rawMessage)
        }
    }
}
```

I can understand the first bit; `socket.on("Hello")`. It declares what to do when the socket receives "Hello". And I also know that `self?.messages.append(rawMessage)` is appending the message to a list. However, the format of the other parts is confusing to me. I am trying to modify it so I can accept any type of data. I think that `if let data = data[0] as? [String:String]` is filtering the data. But when I remove it and its parentheses, XCode throws error's at me. Could you please explain to me this code and how I should go about modifying it?

Comment: This has nothing to do with SwiftUI. SwiftUI is a UI framework. Something like `if data[0]` (first element of an array) is a dictionary with a key that is a `String` and a value that is a `String` put it in `data`. Look at the documentation for `on`

Comment: Thank you, that explains how the if statement is formatted. But what is the second part; ```DispatchQueue.main.async```. I am transferring from another language(s), and I have never seen anything like this. From my understanding, it is putting the ```self?.messages.append(rawMessage)``` in a 'main' process. I don't know why that would have to be done, as I am only working on one process. Thanks for your help!

Comment: UI has to be updated on the main thread and `on` is async (on a background thread)